# Can't send values from angular 2 to spring controller using Rest

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

i'm trying to create a CRUD application , for the Select operation everything is ok but i can't create a new Personne , by sending the values of the form to the spring controller 
this is my app-components.ts

```
        import { personne } from './personne';
    import { StylesCompileResult } from '@angular/compiler';
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'ICS DashBoard Project';
      http: Http;
      contacts = [
        'toto',
        'momo',
        'soso'
      ];
      personne: Observable<personne[]>;
      constructor(http: Http) {
        //http.get('http://localhost:8082/personne/all');
        this.http = http;
        this.http.get('http://localhost:8082/personne/all').subscribe((res: Response) => this.personne = res.json());


      }

      addPersonne(nom: string, prenom: string, age: number, dateNaissance) {


        /*
        console.log(nom);
          this.http.post('http://localhost:8086/personne/save', 
              {"prenom": prenom,
              "nom":nom,
              "age":age,
              "dateNaissance":dateNaissance
          }).toPromise(); * 
         */
        /*
            var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            var body = JSON.stringify( {
            var1:'test',
            var2:'test2'
            });
            var params='json'+body;
            this.http.post('http://validate.jsontest.com', body, headers).map((res: Response) => res.json());
            console.log("ajoutee");
              */
        // var json=JSON.stringify({var1:'test1',var2:3});
        var params = {

          "prenom": prenom,
          "nom": nom,
          "age": age,
          "dateNaissance": dateNaissance
        }

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        //var head = new Headers();
        console.log("TOTO");
        // head.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        /*this.http.post('http://localhost:8082/personne/save',params,{

          headers:head
       }).map(res=> res.json())*/


      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

      this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/sessions/create', params, {
        headers: headers
        })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(


          () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
        );
      }
    /*
    updatePersonne(oldName:string, newName:string){
      console.log("UPDATE");
      this.http.post('http://localhost:8082/personne/update', { "oldName": oldName, "newName": newName });
    }*/
          }
```

this is my rest controller

```
            package org.sqli.Controller;

        import java.util.List;

        import org.sqli.entities.Personne;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
        import org.sqli.service.PersonneService;

        @RestController
        //@CrossOrigin("*")
        //@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
        @RequestMapping(value="/personne")
        public class PersonneRestController {

            @Autowired
            private PersonneService personneService;

            @CrossOrigin
            @RequestMapping(value="/save")
            public Personne savePersonne(@RequestBody Personne p){

                System.out.println("persoone :::"+p.getNom());
                return personneService.savePersonne(p);

            }
        /*  @CrossOrigin
            @RequestMapping(value="/update",method=RequestMethod.POST)
            public Personne updatePersonne(@RequestBody String oldName , String newName){
                List<Personne> lPersonne = listPersonne();
                Personne newPersonne = null;
                for(Personne personne : lPersonne){
                    if(personne.getNom().equals(oldName)){
                        newPersonne = personne;
                        newPersonne.setNom(newName);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    return personneService.updatePersonne(newPersonne);

            }*/

        /*  @CrossOrigin
            @RequestMapping(value="savep",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
            public Personne savePersonnep(@RequestBody Personne p){

                return personneService.savePersonne(p);
            }*/
            @CrossOrigin
            @RequestMapping(value="/all")
            public List<Personne> listPersonne(){
                return personneService.listPersonne();
            }
            @CrossOrigin
            @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
            public void deletePersonne(@PathVariable Long id){
                System.out.println("Delete bien");
                personneService.deletePersonne(id);

            }




        }
```

Comment: What's the result? Error? What is it? What type of debugging have you done? What did you discover?

Comment: I think content type is a problem

Comment: so first i start debugging , the problem the metho savePersonne from my rest controller it's not executed , and when i inspect the network from the browser , the get operation it's done successfully but it's not the same case for the post method , i think the problem is in post function from the app-components.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the request method

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/save", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
public Personne savePersonne(@RequestBody Personne p){

                System.out.println("persoone :::"+p.getNom());
                return personneService.savePersonne(p);

            }
```

and verify the url in the post method of the service( AppComponent/addpersonne)

Comment: yes now the post operation it's done successfully , but i got this error in the debug browser
   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8082/personne/save. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 415.

Comment: i tried to eliminate this instruction 
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
and it's work now , thanks a lot

Comment: So happy for  you !

Answer (score 0):

the url used doesn't match the endpoint of your controller :

```
 //addPersonne
 this.http.post('http://localhost:port/personne/save', params, {
    headers: headers
    })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(


      () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
    );
```